# Mysql select last week sum per day

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query in my report dashboard that shows me total of last 7 days income in one number.

Now I'm trying to get this number on a daily chart , for example :

```
April 7: 100,000 (total income from april 1 to 7)
April 8: 110,000 (total income from april 2 to 8)
...
```

How can I select like this ?

Purchases table structure :

```
Value : int
Date : date
```

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions.  If you have one row per day, this would often be used:

```
select t.*,
       sum(income) over (order by date rows between 6 preceding and current row)
from t;
```

This adds up 7 rows, so if there are missing or duplicate dates it is not correct.

However, `range` really does limit to the dates you want:

```
select t.*,
       sum(income) over (order by date range between interval 6 day preceding and current row)
from t;
```